# Pass ArrayList of custom objects from child activity back to parent

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm making a basic habit tracking app. I have a fragment class called HabitFragment (it's a fragment because it is just one part of a multi-tabbed app) that displays a list of Habits (which are objects of a custom Habit class and contain name, frequency, etc), each of which has a "log" button. This log button takes the user to another activity called HabitLog, where they say at which date and time they performed said habit. In this Activity I have an ArrayList of custom objects which store the date and time of a habit recorded by the user, aptly called HabitDateAndTime. I want to be able to send this ArrayList back to the HabitFragment class on the press of a button. I can't get it to work.

I have tried this in the onCreate method of my HabitLog activity. It is based on what I could find on old posts on this site:

```
    doneButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Intent data = new Intent();
        data.putExtra("dateTimes", gson.toJson(datesAndTimes));
        setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
        finish();
    });
```

and this in the onResume of HabitFragment:

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Intent intent = this.getActivity().getIntent();
    String str = intent.getStringExtra("datesTimes");
    List<HabitDateAndTime> datesTimes = gson.fromJson(str, List.class);
}
```

But when I check the value of datesTimes, it says null even if I add things to it in the child activity.

How do I properly send an ArrayList of custom objects from a child activity to a parent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start your child `Activity` for result using `startActivityForResult()` and then in your child `Activity` set the result, after you have collected your data from the user, using `setResult()` and manually finish your child `Activity` using `finish()`. Then in the `HabitLogFragment` class again, override `onActivityResult()` to receive the data set in your child `Activity`.

Refer to this guide for more in depth information: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.

Comment: Happy to hear and glad to help.